# keep personal notes in meeting invitation

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

I often take notes in meeting invitations so when I join the meeting I immediately access my notes too.

However when I receive an update for the meeting my notes are deleted and only the update is kept, neither a copy of my version is stored in deleted items folder. My version is deleted immediately as I receive the update, so I don't have time to save it before accepting the update.

Is there any way to keep notes in invitations or at least recover them somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks you were editing the meeting directly to add the notes, correct? If so, I'm afraid there is no option available to avoid losing the notes. When you edit the meeting in your Outlook, you are actually editing the copy of the meeting that the meeting organizer sent to you. When an updated version of the meeting is sent from the organizer, your copy of meeting will be replaced with the updated version. Thus, your personal notes in the meeting will be lost.

Try using Meeting Notes with OneNote instead of editing the meeting directly.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although not ideal,  it works at least.